# muliple inputs node red function python

Tags: node-red

I want to write a node red function in python(cause i'm not very familiar with javascript) with multiple inputs but i have no idea how to call the different input messages in the function node.

[image: multiple input python function]

Answer (score 0):

Node-RED nodes only have 1 input, there is nothing in underlying Node-RED that will tell you which node it came from.

Any node will only process one message at a time.

If you need to distinguish messages then you normally use the `msg.topic` field which can be set in most nodes. In the MQTT-in node it will be the MQTT topic the message arrived on.

For the GPIO node it will be configured in the node.